# Moving parts of string around python

Tags: python

I have a string, well, several actually. The strings are simply:

```
string.a.is.this
```

or

```
string.a.im
```

in that fashion.

and what I want to do is make those stings become:

```
this.is.a.string
```

and

```
im.a.string
```

What I've tried:

```
new_string = string.split('.')
new_string = (new_string[3] + '.' + new_string[2] + '.' + new_string[1] + '.' + new_string[0])
```

Which works fine for making:

```
string.a.is.this
```

into

```
this.is.a.string
```

but gives me a error of 'out of range' if I try it on:

```
string.a.im
```

yet if I do:

```
new_string = (new_string[2] + '.' + new_string[1] + '.' + new_string[0])
```

that works fine to make:

```
string.a.im
```

into

```
 im.a.string
```

but obviously does not work for:

```
string.a.is.this
```

since it is not setup for 4 indices.  I was trying to figure out how to make the extra index optional, or any other work around, or, better method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and [`[::-1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> mystr = 'string.a.is.this'
>>> '.'.join(mystr.split('.')[::-1])
'this.is.a.string'
>>> mystr = 'string.a.im'
>>> '.'.join(mystr.split('.')[::-1])
'im.a.string'
>>>
```

To explain better, here is a step-by-step demonstration with the first string:

```
>>> mystr = 'string.a.is.this'
>>>
>>> # Split the string on .
>>> mystr.split('.')
['string', 'a', 'is', 'this']
>>>
>>> # Reverse the list returned above
>>> mystr.split('.')[::-1]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
>>>
>>> # Join the strings in the reversed list, separating them by .
>>> '.'.join(mystr.split('.')[::-1])
'this.is.a.string'
>>>
```

Comment: Excellent. Clear and straight forward answer. And thanks for the extra add-on explanation, as well as the fast response, works exactly as needed.

Comment: You can also use reversed() instead of the slice step.
e.g. '.'.join(reversed(mystr.split('.')))

Answer (score 1):

You could do it through python's `re` module,

```
import re
mystr = 'string.a.is.this'
regex = re.findall(r'([^.]+)', mystr)
'.'.join(regex[::-1])
'this.is.a.string'
```